# Remove space between soft kayboard and button

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using scrollview to scroll my view up when soft keyboard open. But it's make more than required space between button and keyboard.
Can we remove this large space.

Here is my xml code block.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>   android:id="@+id/widget32"
>   android:layout_width="match_parent"
>   android:layout_height="match_parent">
>   <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:fillViewport="true">
>     <RelativeLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>         <EditText
>             android:id="@+id/searchText"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_above="@+id/searchBtn"
>             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>             android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
>             android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
>             android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
>             android:hint="@string/search_hint"
>             android:inputType="number"
>             android:maxLength="10" />
>         <Button
>             android:id="@+id/searchBtn"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>             android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
>             android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
>             android:background="#339933"
>             android:padding="20dp"
>             android:text="@string/search_button_text"
>             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
>             android:textSize="20sp"
>             android:textStyle="bold" />
>     </RelativeLayout>
>  </ScrollView>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align the click button with the software keyboard, it should be at the layouts bottom.

You should have the click button within the root layout, which should have the click button aligned to bottom, either with linearlayouts gravity or relativelayouts layout_alignParentBottom

So basically you define the layout as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout>

<Button
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And ta-da! the button is right on top of the software keyboard!

**The real problem..**

As it turns out in the comments the real problem here is to align the button to the keyboard only when it is visible, which can simply be achieved by having two invidual buttons that visibilitys are toggled based on the keyboard state

So first we define a layout that has two buttons, one for the software keyboard state and one for the "regular" state

```
<RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <!-- ...... -->


        <Button
        android:id="@+id/regular_button">
        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
android:id="@+id/keyboard_aligned_button"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and now we just hook the keyboard state to the visibility of the buttons, so we need in some way to keep track of the keyboard state, which is explained in [many places](http://toastdroid.com/2014/10/14/on-screen-keyboard-state-tracking-in-3-easy-steps/)

and when the keyboard is set to be visible we [setVisibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)) of the regular button to be [GONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE), and keyboard aligned button to [VISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE).

After a keyboard is gone visibilities are inversed

Comment: And what about the initial condition as it was in the middle of layout before the keyboard appear ? For my liking this is not the answer for the required or given layout..

Comment: If you want it to be on top of the software keyboard, it must be the most lowest element in such way that it is aligned to bottom

If you want to keep the initial conditions if the software keyboard is not shown, you can simply add another button that only is visible when the software keyboard is present and manage its visibility

Comment: so this is not the answer according to the given layout look and feel

Comment: You didn't really specify that you want to keep the initial conditions but only have the button aligned to the software keyboard when it is present. But it is easily done by adding another button that is only shown when keyboard is visible and by then hiding the regular button as i explained in my previous comment

Comment: I did'nt ask the question, but before answering you must look at his layout, i guess a picture speaks thousand words..

Comment: Not to be rude here, but in no way does the images imply that only when software keyboard is present should the button be aligned to the bottom.

But I updated the answer for the sake of clarity

Comment: Mr. Pasi Matalamäki your suggestion is very good, but here at this activity i have just "EditText and Button" so I can aligned button on bottom, it will look weird. After all I got some alternative solution of this.